# Group 'libvirtd' does not exist while installing QEMU-KVM

Tags: server, permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using **Ubuntu 17.04 and linux kernel 4.11.3** on a server. The system operates on x86-64 architecture.

I was using the Ubuntu documentation to install **KVM** linked here [Install KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

I have encountered a problem while installing it. I see that the installation of libvirt-bin did not install the group `libvirtd` in my system.

**Edit** : I see that the below groups have been created possibly after the installation -

```
akalita@######:~$ cat /etc/group

kvm:x:120:
libvirt:x:121:#######
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
```

I still cannot find the group **libvirtd**.

So when I go on to run the below command as per the documentation -

```
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
```

I get the below error :-

```
adduser: The group `libvirtd' does not exist.
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Per the instructions, did you "relogin so that your user becomes an effective member of the libvirtd group" ?.  Recently I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 17.x.  For some reason, it did not 
"

Comment: Hi @PJSingh the thing is I cannot see the group libvirtd itself. So I am not able to add my username to that group Does this mean I need to relogin again to see the group appear ?

Comment: OK, always worth checking, though.  The instructions say, "but not 14.04 LTS", so I presume the instructions work for 9.10 up to 13.10, only.  May be there is something different you need to do for releases after 14.04, but I don't have experience with QEMU-KVM; hopefully someone else will provide some insight to your question.

Comment: Yes, @PJSingh, I checked and relogged in. The group still does not exist. You are probably right - for releases with and beyond 14.04 - it is likely that instruction is probably not working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was to manually create the `libvirtd` group:

```
sudo addgroup libvirtd
sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME libvirtd
```

After that: `virt-manager` started without telling me to add myself to the libvirtd group anymore.

Comment: In latest ubuntu the group is libvirt ; (you may  need to restart after installing)

Answer (score 30):

The issue is about the name of the group. 
On Ubuntu, the group name should be "libvirt" ...without "d".

so your command should be:

```
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirt
```

Comment: Nice, this was the issue on Solus too! Or in that case, `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt [username]`

Comment: after that you might need to reboot the system

Comment: This was the issue on Manjaro as well! `sudo usermod -a [username] -G libvirt`

Answer (score 11):

The group was renamed to libvirt for Ubuntu 16.10 and later. It's in the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html.en#libvirt-installation)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on ubuntu 17.04 Desktop

**Workaround:**

In a terminal enter:

```
sudo apt install virt-manager
```

and then

```
sudo virt-manager
```

if you try to start virt-manager using Unity GUI
**Application > virt-manager**
it won't work because your current user does not have the requisite permissions.

Comment: Yes that's because to run virt-manager you seem to need 'root privilege', but that don't seem to be the case while trying to access virt-manager from the **Application menu**. Even from the terminal, if you just enter virt-manager, you will get similar error. It only works when you enter **sudo virt-manager**.