# add user to the libvirtd

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I installed java 11 and I am trying to install kvm. I followed the instructions as given on the official ubuntu website.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

I finished up installing the tool and then as it mentioned on the website that we need to add the user to the libvirtd group. But the terminal is saying that this group(libvirtd) doesn't exist.
I tried this ubuntu question too

[Group 'libvirtd' does not exist while installing QEMU-KVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930491/group-libvirtd-does-not-exist-while-installing-qemu-kvm)

But there is no satisfactory answer for ubuntu versions 14 and later.
How do I add my username to the group.

The output of

```
sudo grep libvirt /etc/group
```

is

```
libvirt:x:129:nik7
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:130:
```

Comment: can we see `grep libvirt /etc/group`

Comment: I have edited the question with the ouput

Comment: So your command ought to have been `sudo adduser \`id -un\` libvirt` so such a group exists. please go back and follow that tutorial carefully the solutions are there!

Comment: do I need to replace `id -un`  with my username. I think you haven't seen my output.

Comment: yes that is what you will see if you run it from the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group 'libvirtd' does not exist while installing QEMU-KVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930491/group-libvirtd-does-not-exist-while-installing-qemu-kvm)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. My ubuntu userame is nik7. So exactly what should I run in the terminal

Comment: if you run `id -un` you will see `nik7` so if that is placed in that code (remember the backticks) it will resolve to `nik7`! But you could also do it this way `sudo adduser $(id -un) libvirt`, which is the preferred way I am told

Comment: So I am running  sudo adduser nik7 libvirt. Same output is coming.   The group `libvirtd' does not exist.

Comment: You are already a member of that group `libvirt:x:129:nik7` didn't see it earlier !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84795/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-nikhil-rathore).

Comment: waiting for your reply in the chat

Comment: I am waiting for you in the chat